# Recorded Audio Files

Tags: iphone, audio, download, documents, recording

i have a application in which i record the user voice and save it into documents folder. now i want to get it back in to the photo library of the iphone or i want to download it so that user can share it with anybody.i am sending mail of the recorded file but if the file size is greated than 8 mb its not allo me to send the email with attachment so in such situation i want to downlod it. so how can get it please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option would be to post the file to a server or cloud, like Amazon s3, where you or someone else could download the file after it is recorded.